# Command-line utility to send notifications to Notification Center in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, command-line, notifications

Is there any command-line utility that sends notifications to Notification Center? Something similar to Growl's `growlnotify`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out [terminal-notifier on GitHub](https://github.com/julienXX/terminal-notifier).

Answer (score 3):

In Maverics it's possible to trigger a notification from an Apple Script, but not sure if it works in Mountain Lion:

```
display notification "Hello!"
```

I made a simple command-line script to pass parameters to an apple script. One-line install:

```
echo -e '#!/bin/bash\n/usr/bin/osascript -e "display notification \"$*\""'|sudo -s "cd /usr/local/bin;tee notify&&chmod +x notify"
```

Will output code below to /usr/local/bin (must exist) and add executable flag. Make sure /usr/local/bin is in your $PATH.

```
#! /bin/bash
/usr/bin/osascript -e "display notification \"$*\""
```

Now to display a notification:

```
notify "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
sleep 5 ; notify "Slow command finished"
```